# Powerpoint VBA Positioning listview

Tags: vba, listview, powerpoint

I am trying to get 2 listview objects to work on a powerpoint slide. I can place them anywhere on the slide, but when I start the slideshow, 2 smaller copies appear in the upper-left corner. Text added to the listview appear in the upper-left boxes. I can't select the original listview either.

How can I prevent the 2 copies from showing up so I can work with the listviews I positioned on the slide?

The slide
http://prnt.sc/ectyx6

The Slideshow
http://prnt.sc/ectz8u

Answer (score 0):

I looked into it a bit, and I think it's just a glitch with the Listview control.

From my tests, the actual Listview control was smaller then the original, but the top left position was correct (after the first time in reading/presentation view).  I assume the they are smaller because it doesn't have a zoom property, and the slide is stretched to fit the window.

If you really want a Listview...which I hate to call into question, but think is warranted...then you can just **Insert a Rectangle without a border** over the Listview control to hide the original placeholder.  The real Listview will still get drawn on top.

I think this is just the beginning of your troubles with a Listview control in PowerPoint...are you sure that you need it.  Maybe linking to an Excel file with the Listview would be better, or some use of animation.

Comment: This won't work, sinds I need two listviews on the  Slide. What I Am trying to reach is a table that I can fill with Some textboxes in a userform. All this during the slideshow. I thought the best way to do this is by using a listview, since filling cells in a table doesn't work during a slideshow bout only when I end the slideshow.

Comment: Perhaps you should create Userform then... and make sure it's Modeless by setting `ShowModal = FALSE`